# Как называется всплывающее окно с адресной строкой?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Доброго времени суток.

Вопрос, скорее всего, дебильный, но я бы хотел спросить, как называется всплывающе окно, которое часто на сайтах используют для авторизации? Например, как на сайте юкоз http://nw.ucoz.com/ - если нажать кнопку авторизации, скажем, в контакте - это окно и всплывет!

Comment: Нет, гугл все равно выдает по запросу "модальное окно с адресной строкой" высплывающие дивы. (

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это никакое не модальное окно. Модальное окно блокирует родительское.

Это обычно окно браузера. В англоязычной литературе называется просто popup window. В наше время, когда вкладки в браузере - норма, а браузер без вкладок просто не может существовать, уже и не могут идентифицировать. :)

Посмотреть пример можно [здесь](http://www.idocs.com/tags/linking/linking_famsupp_72.html).

Comment: Ну или [здесь еще пример](http://javascript.ru/window-open)